# Shopify script tag not rendering

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, shopify, koa

## the problem

I created a Shopify node.js app using the Shopify CLI and I want to display a simple bar under the header using a script tag. I used the script tag API to add a script tag

```
"script_tags": [
    {
        "id": 174240039086,
        "src": "https://xxxxx.ngrok.io/script_tag",
    }
]
```

And I also added  a `<div id="script-app"></div>` into the theme, under the header.

Here is my script_tag.js file, located in /pages/script_tag.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class TestScriptTag extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>this is a bar</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

 ReactDOM.render(<TestScriptTag />, document.getElementById('script-app'));

export default TestScriptTag;
```

Lastly, here is my server.js (most of it is what came with the CLI):

```
import "@babel/polyfill";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import "isomorphic-fetch";
import createShopifyAuth, { verifyRequest } from "@shopify/koa-shopify-auth";
import Shopify, { ApiVersion } from "@shopify/shopify-api";
import Koa from "koa";
import next from "next";
import Router from "koa-router";
import { flushSync } from "react-dom";

const fs = require('fs');

dotenv.config();
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 8083;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const app = next({
  dev,
});
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

Shopify.Context.initialize({
  API_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
  API_SECRET_KEY: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET,
  SCOPES: process.env.SCOPES.split(","),
  HOST_NAME: process.env.HOST.replace(/https:\/\//, ""),
  API_VERSION: ApiVersion.October20,
  IS_EMBEDDED_APP: false,
  // This should be replaced with your preferred storage strategy
  SESSION_STORAGE: new Shopify.Session.MemorySessionStorage(),
});

// Storing the currently active shops in memory will force them to re-login when your server restarts. You should
// persist this object in your app.
const ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS = {};

app.prepare().then(async () => {
  const server = new Koa();
  const router = new Router();
  
  server.keys = [Shopify.Context.API_SECRET_KEY];
  server.use(
    createShopifyAuth({
      async afterAuth(ctx) {
        console.log("here")
        // Access token and shop available in ctx.state.shopify
        const { shop, accessToken, scope } = ctx.state.shopify;
        const host = ctx.query.host;
        ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop] = scope;

        const response = await Shopify.Webhooks.Registry.register({
          shop,
          accessToken,
          path: "/webhooks",
          topic: "APP_UNINSTALLED",
          webhookHandler: async (topic, shop, body) =>
            delete ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop],
        });

        if (!response.success) {
          console.log(
            `Failed to register APP_UNINSTALLED webhook: ${response.result}`
          );
        }

        // Redirect to app with shop parameter upon auth
        ctx.redirect(`/?shop=${shop}&host=${host}`);
      },
    })
  );

  const handleRequest = async (ctx) => {
    await handle(ctx.req, ctx.res);
    ctx.respond = false;
    ctx.res.statusCode = 200;
  };

  router.get("/", async (ctx) => {
    const shop = ctx.query.shop;

    // This shop hasn't been seen yet, go through OAuth to create a session
    if (ACTIVE_SHOPIFY_SHOPS[shop] === undefined) {
      ctx.redirect(`/auth?shop=${shop}`);
    } else {
      await handleRequest(ctx);
    }
  });

  router.get("/script_tag", (ctx) => {
    handleRequest(ctx);
  });


  router.get("(/_next/static/.*)", handleRequest); // Static content is clear
  router.get("/_next/webpack-hmr", handleRequest); // Webpack content is clear
  router.get("(.*)", verifyRequest(), handleRequest); // Everything else must have sessions


  server.use(router.allowedMethods());
  server.use(router.routes());
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

I am getting the error: `document not defined`.

## What I've tried

I thought this is due to server side rendering, so I thought I could get around it by doing this:

```
 if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
   ReactDOM.render(<TestScriptTag />, document.getElementById('script-app'));
}
```

But still nothing renders and I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ke73d.png) when I inspect the shop page.

I've also tried changing the routing to this:

```
  router.get("/script_tag", (ctx) => {
    ctx.type = "module";
    ctx.body = fs.createReadStream('./pages/script_tag.js')
  });
```

But then I get an error about the import statement in script_tag.js - `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier '{'. import call expects exactly one argument.`

I'm not sure what the proper way is to serve the javascript file I want to inject into the header. I feel like I'm missing something stupid. Please help!!

Comment: Are you using your compiled js file and not the src one? I see an import statement in your error, which means that you are using your SRC file, please compile it and use your BUILD js file instead.

Comment: @drip This might be a stupid question, but how do I compile it? The app generated by the Shopify CLI uses Next which would pre-render the page?

Comment: The Nextjs part is separate from the ScriptTag API. The Nextjs handles the app inside the admin panel so everything is done for you, but with the ScriptTag API you are requesting a static js file, this means that this file must be compiled to meet the javascript standards, a.k.a `react` & `import` are not standards so you need to compile them using `webpack` and `babel` or drop the react and import and use just plain javascript. Or to say it simply if you paste your code in the development console it must work, if throws an error it will not work for the ScriptTag API.